# Question on inequality with Euclidean norm in $\;\mathbb R^n\;$

Tags: calculus, normed-spaces, absolute-value

We know that for the absolute value $\; \vert \bullet \vert\;$ it holds: $\;\vert xy \vert \ge xy\;\; \forall x,y \in \mathbb R$

Now if I consider $\; f,g:\mathbb R \supset (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb R^n\;$ **would the above inequality be still valid?** To be more specific, is it true that $\;\vert fg \vert \ge f g\;$?

**EDIT:** $\;fg\;$ is the inner product.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the problem is that you're using $fg$ two times with different meanings. Clarify yourself first

Comment: @Exodd What do you mean? $f(x)=(f_1(x), \dots , f_n(x))\;$ and $g(x)=(g_1(x), \dots , g_n(x))\;$ and $\;fg\;$ is the inner product

Comment: @kaithkolesidou If $fg$ is the inner product, $fg$ is a real number, so the absolute value for it obeys your condition. But it is not the form that you have wrote. It is not $\sqrt{(f_1g_1)^2+...(f_ng_n)^2}$. It is  $\sqrt{(f_1g_1+...+f_ng_n)^2}$

Comment: @Andrei Oh I just realised my mistake! Thanks for pointing it out! I'll edit my post!